# Show popup in recyclerView exactly where the button is, in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-popupwindow

I'm working on a gridLayout with recyclerView in android.I've a an option with each grid Item  where I want to show my popup activity which is another class. Please see the image - 
[image]

There is a menu option with each Item. and my popup activity java name is **CustomPop.Class**. I use a recyclerView for showing gridViews and its holder method is like

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.img_chatroom_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ChatroomPopup.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

By this I can show the popup activity. But the problem is It's appear in the middle of the activity but I want it to open beside the menu option.

Comment: use  **popup menu**

Comment: for popup menu what to write ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[as per my above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440245/show-popup-in-recyclerview-exactly-where-the-button-is-in-android#comment79836717_46440245)**  you can use  **[Popup Menu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)**

> Android Popup Menu displays the menu below the anchor text if space is available otherwise above the anchor text. It disappears if you click outside the popup menu.

try this create menu file

file: poupup_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/one"  
        android:title="One"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/two"  
        android:title="Two"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/three"  
        android:title="Three"/>  

</menu>
```

than use create popup menu like this

```
holder.img_chatroom_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

           @Override  
           public void onClick(View v) {  
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu  
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button1);  
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());  

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener  
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
             public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
              return true;  
             }  
            });  

            popup.show();//showing popup menu  
           }  
          });//closing the setOnClickListener method
```

here is the sample demo links **[how to create pop-up menu in android](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=how%20to%20crete%20popup%20menu%20in%20andorid&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=gTzLWdy4COXy8Ae78rWAAw)**

Comment: So can I customize the popup menus from here?

Comment: @TanvirDurlove customize menas can you explain more

Comment: because if my list goes long it looks a little bit weired a tall list.

Comment: what do you want to display in that pop up menu

Comment: I just want to set its hight/width manually by my self, and make a background.

Comment: For design purpose

Comment: when you use pop up menu don't worry about design it will manage

Answer (score 2):

You should have to use popup menu to achieve what you want just as follow :

Create a menu user `res > menu > your_menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_one"
        android:title="Item One" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_two"
        android:title="Item Two" />
</menu>
```

Put above code into your `style.xml`

```
<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <!--<item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>-->
    </style>
```

In your respective `RecyclerView Adapter`

```
holder.myAlbumsOptionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.popupMenuStyle);
                final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v, Gravity.END);
                popup.inflate(R.menu.your_menu);

                popup.show();

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.menu_item_one:

                                //Do operation if menu_item_one

                                break;
                            case R.id.menu_item_two:

                                //Do operation if menu_item_two

                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

To know more about [**PopupMenu**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)

Comment: but how to resize this popup or customize?

Comment: @TanvirDurlove you can change the menu to achieve some customization like showing icon